# Sending a request in ASP.NET Core API 2.1 with a header with non-ASCII characters

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api, character-encoding, asp.net-core-2.1

I have a very simple ASP.NET Core API. I'm sending headers to this service and it works well.

But the problem is that when I send a character such like "á" in a request header, the request fails with `400: Bad request`.

I know this is not a problem with the client—I tested the same code against a Java API and it worked. I also reproduced the same problem with Postman.

How can I tell the server to accept UTF-8 in the request headers?

```cs
[HttpPut("/api/Test")]
public IActionResult test([FromHeader(Name = "Word")] String word)
{
  return Ok("I accepted your request");
}
```

[image: Screenshot of Postman]

### Edit:

It worked with 3.1, so now we know this is 2.1 related.

Comment: I don't believe this is currently supported: https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/4727

Comment: Sorry, that's responses. I believe headers was supported by this change: https://github.com/aspnet/KestrelHttpServer/pull/2867/files

Comment: @MartinCostello So, how can I implement it?

Comment: if it's not working, you could base64 encode your header value.

Comment: @ChristophLütjen Yes, thank you, that's what I did and it worked, but this is SO TERRIBLE, there must be a way, i refuse to believe that this is not supported.

Comment: I created a default webAPI project to test and it works on my machine (.net core 3.0 and 3.1). Do you have any middleware or anything else that can intercept the request ?

Comment: @CyrilDurand No middleware. Version 2.1 (not that old)

Comment: FYI: Since @CyrilDurand reports that this works on ASP.NET Core 3.0+, and @CarlosLópezMarí reports that this is on ASP.NET Core 2.1, I've added the `asp.net-core-2.1` tag to this post, as it seems like it _may_ be a specific issue with previous version of ASP.NET. (If so, though, I imagine there may be a GitHub issue on the topic; I haven't looked.)

Comment: @JeremyCaney I reproduced the issue using 2.1 but not with 2.2. The following github issue contains lot of interesting information about this behavior https://github.com/aspnet/KestrelHttpServer/issues/1144. Could you upgrade to v2.2 or not using Kestrel ?

Comment: @CyrilDurand May you post this as an answer, I would accept it as the correct one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is a limitation of .net core 2.1 and it has been fixed with .net core 2.2.

There is more information about this behavior in this github issue [Configure header parsing to allow non-compliant headers](https://github.com/aspnet/KestrelHttpServer/issues/1144)

I can see the following solution to fix this issue :

- migrate to .net core 2.2 or above
- Url encode header from the client side
- Use a reverse proxy to encode header before it hits your ASP.net application

Comment: @CarlosLópezMarí You are right. By default IIS integration acts as a reverse proxy to Kestrel server. I remember that you can configure IIS without Kestrel but can't find the documentation how. I saw this one : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/servers/httpsys?view=aspnetcore-3.1 but I have not tested it.